# Spark - convert array of JSON Strings to Struct array, filter and concat with root

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am totally new to Spark and I'm writing a pipeline to perform some transformations into a list of audits.

Example of my data:

```
{
    "id": 932522712299,
    "ticket_id": 12,
    "created_at": "2020-02-14T19:05:16Z",
    "author_id": 392401450482,
    "events": ["{\"id\": 932522713292, \"type\": \"VoiceComment\", \"public\": false, \"data\": {\"from\": \"11987654321\", \"to\": \"+1987644\"}"],
}
```

My schema is basically:

```
root
 |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- ticket_id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- created_at: string (nullable = true)
 |-- author_id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- events: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

My transformations has a few steps:

- Split events by type: comments, tags, change or update;
- For each event found, I must add ticket_id, author_id and created_at from root;
- It must have one output for each event type.

Basically, each object inside event's array is a string JSON because each type has a different structure - the only attribute common between them it's the `type`.

I have reach my goals doing some terrible work by converting my dataframe to dict using the following code:

```
audits = list(map(lambda row: row.asDict(), df.collect()))`
comments = []
for audit in audits:
    base_info = {'ticket_id': audit['ticket_id'], 'created_at': audit['created_at'], 'author_id': audit['author_id']}
    audit['events'] = [json.loads(x) for x in audit['events']]

    audit_comments = [
        {**x, **base_info}
        for x in audit['events']
        if x['type'] == "Comment" or x['type'] == "VoiceComment"
    ]
    comments.extend(audit_comments)
```

Maybe this question sounds lame or lazy but I'm really stuck in simple things like:

- how to parse 'events' items to struct?
- how to select event by type and add informations from root? Maybe using select syntax?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `events` array elements don't have the same structure for all rows, what you can do is convert it to a `Map(String, String)`.

Using [`from_json`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#from_json) function and the schema `MapType(StringType(), StringType())`:

```
df = df.withColumn("events", explode("events"))\
       .withColumn("events", from_json(col("events"), MapType(StringType(), StringType())))
```

Then, using [`element_at`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#element_at) (Spark 2.4+), you can get the `type` like this:

```
df = df.withColumn("event_type", element_at(col("events"), "type"))

df.printSchema()

#root
 #|-- author_id: long (nullable = true)
 #|-- created_at: string (nullable = true)
 #|-- events: map (nullable = true)
 #|    |-- key: string
 #|    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)
 #|-- id: long (nullable = true)
 #|-- ticket_id: long (nullable = true)
 #|-- event_type: string (nullable = true)
```

Now, you can filter and select as normal columns:

```
df.filter(col("event_type") == lit("VoiceComment")).show(truncate=False)

#+------------+--------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+---------+------------+
#|author_id   |created_at          |events                                                                                                     |id          |ticket_id|event_type  |
#+------------+--------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+---------+------------+
#|392401450482|2020-02-14T19:05:16Z|[id -> 932522713292, type -> VoiceComment, public -> false, data -> {"from":"11987654321","to":"+1987644"}]|932522712299|12       |VoiceComment|
#+------------+--------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+---------+------------+
```

Comment: The schema for `events` might be `T.ArrayType(T.MapType(T.StringType(), T.StringType()))` instead of `T.MapType(T.StringType(), T.StringType())`, since `events` can contain multiple events, (e.g. it is an array of maps). It least that's the way I read it.

Answer (score 1):

Your code will load the complete events data onto the master node, which has submitted the job. The spark way to process data wants you to create a map reduce job.  There are multiple api for this - they create a DAG Plan for the job and the plan is manifested only when calling specific functions like `head or show`. 
A job like this will be distributed to all machines in a cluster.

When working with a dataframe api, a lot can be done with `pyspark.sql.functions`

Below the same tranformations with spark.sql dataframe api

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = df.withColumn('event', F.explode(df.events)).drop(df.events)
df = df.withColumn('event', F.from_json(df.event, 'STRUCT <id: INT, type: STRING, public: Boolean, data: STRUCT<from: STRING, to: STRING>>'))
events = df.where('event.type = "Comment" OR event.type == "VoiceComment"')

events.printSchema()
events.head(100)
```

When data cannot be processed with sql expressions you can implement a plain user defined function - UDF or Pandas UDF